# Android Launcher icon not showing

Tags: android, android-manifest, launcher

I have a problem with my app launcher icon. Launcher icon is not shown on device. Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name=".HamrahBankAnsarApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

The confusing point is when I move
`<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>`
to the MainActivity tag, the launcher icon is displayed. But the launcher activity is LoginActivity and it must be opened before MainActivity.
Can anybody help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by luncher icon  , app icon or luncher screen (splash )

Comment: if you mean luncher icon , app icon check your android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" , ctrl and click then check icon

Comment: I meant app icon which is shown in applications page on device. It is called launcher icon because it is displayed on the device's launcher app.

Comment: Just shifting the intent filter to Main Activity shows your launcher icon? you change nothing else for that??

Comment: @Yashasvi yes exactly like you said. it is so confusing

Comment: You may try to specify the `android:icon` attribute for the `<activity>` as well.

Comment: @Floern I have already tried that but not working

Comment: Which class does `LoginActivity` extend?

Comment: Both activites extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: Are you using Instant Run? Try rebuilding your app and deploying the APK.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma I'm not using Instant Run and I have cleaned and rebuilt project multiple times but still not showing. I have noticed something that the app icon is shown on another device. Does it relate to the mipmap folders? I tried to rename ic_launcher file but still not shown.

Comment: make sure your mipmap contain all sizes and I dont think its not related to intent filter

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing all bitmaps that are called `ic_launcher.png` in your mipmap resources. One should be provided in every density bin, including the `xxxhdpi` bin.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your icon is in all resolution folders like below:

```
 res/...
    mipmap-ldpi/...
        ic_launcher.png
    mipmap-mdpi/...
        ic_launcher.png
    mipmap-hdpi/...
        ic_launcher.png
    mipmap-xhdpi/...
        ic_launcher.png
    mipmap-xxhdpi/...
        ic_launcher.png
```

Answer (score 0):

set below the line in your application tag below `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

```
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

It will help you a lot. Happy Coding!!!